# pagenumber in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I write my thesis and face several problems when writing a table of contents. The page numbers of the list of tables and shapes are incorrect. For example, if the table list consists of two pages, the second page number appears in the table of contents, and I do not know the reason. I use

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Contents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{\LARGE List of Symbols} 
\end{flushleft}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Symbols}
\begin{tabular}{l}
nbm;lkhj\\
ghjkkllkl\\
\end{flushleft}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{\LARGE Abbreviations}
\end{flushleft}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\begin{tabular}{l}
ghjkllllll\\
fdfghjkllll\\
ffghjkjkkkkk
\end{tabular}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Tables}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
\clearpage

The other problem appears in the header of the list of icons (consisting of two or more pages) the name of the table of contents. I use

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
     {\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
```

I need help me

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! It is advised to first read [How to create a minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). We are happy to help!

Comment: Please need help, the second page number of the contents, the list of tables and the list of shapes appears in the table of contents, and this problem I do not know how to solve.

Comment: So you want to have the table on content by itself? How about the list of figures, abbreviation, symbols, etc., do you want a special page for the figures, then another one for only abbreviation, and another one for only symbols?

Comment: The formula I used above. The problem in the table of contents. For example, the numbering of list of tables (Which consists of two pages)  shows the second page number in the table of contents.

Comment: So you only want the table of content to be on a page be itself?

Comment: Contents
Abstract                                                             iv
Declaration                                                        vi
Contents                                                            ix
List of Symbols                                                   x
Abbreviations                                                     xii
List of Tables                                                     xiv
List of Figures                                                   xvi

Comment: The table of contents appears in this way knowing that the contents  in a page(vii) , list of table in page (xiii) and list of figures in page (xv)

Comment: Give me about 24 hours and I will post a solution. I will improve upon your code so that the listings of the figures, tables, etc. are done automatically. I have been busy for the last a few days but I didn't forget about your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything

Answer (score 1):

As I promised you, here is a complete minimal working example fulfilling your desire. Keep in mind that it might be slightly different than what you wanted but you can very easily change it.

Note that you must **compile twice** before viewing the document.

I have used the `glossaries` package to help out regarding the abbreviations.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % For sample images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, toc, section = section]{glossaries}

% Add the abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}

\makenoidxglossaries % Need this!

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage % Removes the empty page between chapters

% fancy header stuff:
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
     {\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    % Add the abstract here
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    Abstract here!!!
    \clearpage
    % Add the declaration here
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
    \chapter*{Declaration}
    Declaration here!!!
    \clearpage

    % Add the list of symbols
    \chapter*{List of Symbols}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
    \begin{tabular}{cp{0.75\textwidth}}
        $x$ & x variable \\
        $y$ & y variable \\
        $z$ & z variable \\
    \end{tabular}

    % Add the list of abbreviations
    \setglossarysection{chapter}
    \printnoidxglossary[title={Abbreviations}, type = acronym]%

    % Add the list of figures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage

    % Add the list of tables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage


    % Start actual content.
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \chapter{Introdution}
    Here are the abbreviations we have: \gls{ny}, \gls{la}.
    Now, they will be used again: \gls{ny}, \gls{la}.\\
    Next we have the first table:
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}\hline
            1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
            4 & 5 & 6\\\hline
            7 & 8 & 9\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Our first table in the book.}
    \end{table}
    Then, our first figure:
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Our first figure in the book.}
    \end{figure}

    We add our second table:
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}\hline
            11 & 22 & 33\\\hline
            44 & 55 & 66\\\hline
            77 & 88 & 99\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Our second table in the book.}
    \end{table}

    Finally, we add the second figure:
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Our second figure in the book.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of option openany?

Comment: Why don't you use smaller pages for the example? Lot's of screenshots of almost completely empty pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer.